# how to get data from middleware on the cloud app routes page

Tags: next.js

In short, I'm trying to use the `WebView` component from my react-native application to access the project page that was created on next js with app routes using the **POST** method and transmit some information. The problem is that I can't get this data on the page.

nextjs version 13.4.9 and 14.0.4

the structure of my project

```
app/assistant/page.tsx 
middleware.ts 
utils/getObjectFromRequestBodyStream.tsx
```

**middleware.ts**

```
import {NextResponse} from 'next/server';
import {getObjectFromRequestBodyStream} from "@/src/utils/getObjectFromRequestBodyStream";

export async function middleware(req: any) {
if (req.method === 'POST' && req.next Url.pathname.includes('/assistant')) {
const custom Data = await getObject From Request Body Stream(req.body);

// // return Next Response.json({ ...custom Data }); - if you use this, I see the data on the page, but I don't see the page component itself

return Next Response.next();
}

return Next Response.next();
}
```

**getObjectFromRequestBodyStream.tsx**

```
export async function getObjectFromRequestBodyStream(body: any) {
const input = await body.getReader().read();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
const string = decoder.decode(input.value);
return JSON.parse(string);
}
```

**assistant/page.tsx**

```
I'm not completely sure what should be here
```

I tried this getServerSideProps or getInitialProps, but I found out that this is only available for pages routes...